# Computing the derivatives of function in Excel

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose displacement is a function of time as follow:
$$s = 3 t^2 + 4$$
Then velocity (first derivative) is
$$\frac{\delta s}{\delta t} = 6 t$$

And acceleration (second derivative) is
$$\frac{\delta^2 s}{\delta t^2} = 6$$

Now, I am trying to illustrate this in excel and this is when things become confusing to me.
For the first derivative - velocity, i took the first difference of displacement column `ds`,and divide this by the first difference of time column `dt`. Yet, none of the velocity I computed is equal to $6 t$. Why is that ?

For the second derivative - acceleration, I took the difference of `ds` column and divide this by differencing the `dt` column. Things become even more confusing here. Thought acceleration should be constant and equal to $6$ at all times. Yet my numbers are wild and off the chart. Why is this happening ? What did I misunderstand? How can i obtain a constant acceleration here ?

For the second derivative, should I be doing (1) or (2) below ?

(1) taking first difference of `ds` and divide this by taking first difference of `dt`

**OR**

(2) taking first difference of `ds` and divide this by **squaring** `dt`, which is `(dt)^2` ?

[image]

Comment: the derivative $\dfrac{ds}{dt}$ is the limit of the ratio $\dfrac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$ as $\Delta t\to0$

Comment: also, for $\dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2}$, you want the limit of $\dfrac {v(t+\Delta t)-v(t)}{\Delta t}$, which is different from what you did; try taking $t=300, 301, 302, 303, $ and $304$ so $\Delta t$ is relatively smaller

Comment: Your "derivative" is the slope of a secant: $\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t} = \frac{s(t_1)-s(t_2)}{t_1-t_2}$. This is (for quadratic functions) the derivative $\frac{ds}{dt}(t)$ at $t=\frac{t_1+t_2}{2}$.

Comment: This is a good exercise to check understanding of derivatives ($+1$)

Comment: $\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}$ is simply the notation we use to differentiate $s$ twice (the "numerator") with respect to $t$ twice (the "denominator").  At no point do we actually square anything (but I can see how the notation can be confusing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, the derivative $\dfrac{ds}{dt}$ is the limit of the ratio $\dfrac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$ as $\Delta t$ approaches $0$.

In the spreadsheet below, I did the calculations with relatively small values of $\Delta t$,

and $ds/dt$ *is* close to $6t$.

Also, for $\dfrac {d^2s}{dt^2}$, you want the limit of $\dfrac{v(t+\Delta t)-v(t)}{\Delta t}$, which is different from what you did,

and you can see it is $6$ as expected.

[image]